# Angular Material date-picker Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

Angular v1.5.5 
Angular Material v1.08

**HTML Code:**

```
<md-dialog>
<md-dialog-content>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="datePicker.data" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
</md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog>
```

**JS code:**

```
 link: function (scope, element) {

                element.bind('click', function (ev) {
                    $mdDialog
                        .show({
                            controller: ctrl,
                            templateUrl: 'view.html',
                            parent: angular.element(document.body),
                            targetEvent: ev,
                            clickOutsideToClose: false
                        });
                });
            }
```

**Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop**

10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":19,"oldVal":18}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":20,"oldVal":19}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":21,"oldVal":20}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":22,"oldVal":21}],[{"msg":"fn: function (c,e,f,g){f=d&&g?g[0]:a(c,e,f,g);return b(f,c,e)}","newVal":23,"oldVal":22}]]

**Does someone has an idea why this is happening?**

Comment: Which directive ? DO share a demo/fiddle ..

Comment: md-datepicker directive. When I open the datepicker throws this error

Comment: Can you share a fiddle/codepen ?